# How to create a new Rails application from existing source code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've been tasked to get a Ruby-on-Rails application working on a dev machine. We have the actual source code (after generation) on a DVD.

I've installed Ruby and Rails, and confirmed both to work. I've copied the source code into C:\Sites.

I'm completely new to the whole stack and googling has given me no help.

Update: took the equivalent of a working day spread over two days. thanks for the answer. got it done in the end. o_O

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already have the code than fire following commands and you are ready to go

```
cd "your project"
bundle install
rake db:migrate
rails server
```

and goto `http://localhost:3000`

Comment: considering he has rvm installed, .rvmrc file and gemset created, right?

Comment: you probably mean `rake db:setup`

Comment: i ended up doing this anyway, although throwing in a thousand and one more commands at the commandline. lol